# INVALID_TOKEN_FORMAT

Tags: docusignapi

I am just looking into integration options and have setup a dev account and am working on the basic `login_information` endpoint. I have followed the documentation and tried using the XML and JSON options when setting the headers.

Both return the same message:

XML:

```
<errorCode>INVALID_TOKEN_FORMAT</errorCode>
<message>The security token format does not conform to expected schema.</message>
```

JSON:

```
{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_TOKEN_FORMAT",
  "message": "The security token format does not conform to expected schema."
}
```

I have made another token and tried that, I have also checked that there is no backslash `(\)` character in my password. I have tried with the API Username and my email address. The Tokens both have 32 characters and 4 `(-)` and are being submitted as utf8.

The XML GET:

Headers:

`BE_HTTP_Set_Custom_Header ( 
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication:" ;
    "<DocuSignCredentials>
        <IntegratorKey>" & integrator_key & "</IntegratorKey>
        <Username>” & username & ”</Username>
        <Password>” & password & ”</Password>
    </DocuSignCredentials>"
)`

Where the quote data e.g. “ & integrator_key & “ is pulling the data from the database.

`BE_HTTP_Set_Custom_Header ( "Content-Type" ; "application/xml" )`

GET:

`BE_GetURL ( 
"https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information?api_password=true&include_account_id_guid=true&login_settings=all" ; "" )`

The JSON GET:

Headers:

`BE_HTTP_Set_Custom_Header ( 
"X-DocuSign-Authentication:" ;
    "{
        \"Username\":\"” & username & ”\",
        \"Password\":\"” & password & ”\",
        \"IntegratorKey\":\"" & integrator_key & "\"
    }"
)`

Where the quoted data  e.g. “ & integrator_key & “ is pulling the data from the database, here I need to escape the " of the JSON with the \ e.g. `\"`.

`BE_HTTP_Set_Custom_Header ( "Content-Type" ; "application/json" )`

GET:

`BE_GetURL ( 
"https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information" ; "" )`

Comment: Please show the actual API request(s) you are making, without that it's very hard for others to debug.  Specifically we need to see the endpoint you are hitting along with the request body, you can redact any private info you don't want to share.

Comment: I will add the API Requests, but I am not sure it will make much sense as I am using FileMaker with the BaseElements plugin to set the Headers and then the XML GET:

Comment: I added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

The login_information method is used to obtain information about a user *only* when you're using Legacy Authentication.

[You should first decide](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html) if you're writing a User App (where the user will be present to authenticate herself) or a Service Integration that will run autonomously in the background.

Then use the appropriate authentication.

[A beta recipe that demonstrates both authentication models](https://github.com/docusign/esignature-recipes-python).

**Added**

Check that your password doesn't include a reserved XML character that needs to be escaped. < and & need to be replaced with the appropriate entity sequence.

And try authenticating with your email, pw, and integration key via the recipe referenced above. If it works, then the problem is in your code. If it doesn't work then something's wrong with your credentials.

Also, check that when you add an http header that you should include the colon with the header key value.

Comment: Thanks, we need to use the Legacy Authentication, and I am just using the most basic call to get it working after that I can look at the other methods.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the special characters in the password, as I saw there could have been an issue from the start I made the password from only alphanumeric characters...